# ArcGIS 10.5 add-ins folder issue

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, add-in, arcgis-10.5

I have ArcGIS 10.5 and some add-ins which I want to be automatically updated after making some corrections. Recently I have found a function that provides ArcGIS to do it. This is all about Add-in Manager - [setting custom folder with add-ins](http://desktop.arcgis.com/ru/arcmap/latest/analyze/python-addins/sharing-and-installing-add-ins.htm).
Once I set a folder and my tools appeared but now I want to change or delete this folder. I removed this folder from box in Add-In Manager and after restarting ArcMap nothing changed. The path to a folder still exists despite I removed it manually.
Almost the same thing about other users - they are not able to save this path and as a result they are not able to setup tools automatically.
Looks like the thing is about overwriting some of ArcGIS parameters, it blocks them. On 10.2 everything works pretty well.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution: the file which has value of path to shared add-ins.
Used for ArcGIS 10.5

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.5
```

The file is called ***AddInFoldersList.xml***